# Azure in China and the great firewall, centralized database?

Tags: azure, firewall, centralized

I have this application thats using a centralized database located outside of the firewall.
I need to run an azure-china hosted instance of my application. 
I have had some issues with getting the application to start and I'm not quite sure why. One thing that struck me is that I have heard a lot of rumors regarding a Chinese firewall. Could this be the problem? That the Chinese application can't request my centralized database?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Beijing and I don't think it's because the GFW. You can RDP to the virtual machine or cloud service instance and try to PING or TELNET to your database address to see if it's a connection issue. And just a kind reminder, check the firewall rule of your database if you are using SQL Azure.

Just my 2 cents hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is very normal when you are doing cross-border projects.

Apart from the GFW, the public internet connection from/to China is neither stable, you can get a generous amount of packet loss.

To get a centralised database accessing in China, a common practise it to use a tunnel to bridge the server and the database. IPsec VPN, OpenVPN, MPLS or even a dedicated line can work pretty well.

Another though is why not try some other providers.